# Sort an array in a spiral with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need some help with this codewars challenge. When this is the input:

```js
array = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
]
```

The output of `snail(array)` should be this `[1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5]` – the numbers sorted in a spiral.

Below is my code, this works in largest arrays too, but the last number of the spiral is missing, help! Thanks in advance.

```js
var snail = function(arr) {

  console.log(arr);
 var x = arr.length - 1;
 var output = [];

    for(h = 0; h < x; h++){
        console.log(h);     
        for(i = h; i < x - h; i++) {
            output.push(arr[h][i]);
        }    
        for(j = h; j < x - h; j++) {
            output.push(arr[j][x - h]);
        }    
        for(k = h; k < x - h; k++) {
            output.push(arr[x - h][x - k]);
        }  
        for(l = h; l < x - h; l++) {
            output.push(arr[x - l][h]);
        }
    }

if(arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
}
return output;            // Outputs [1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4]   // there should be 5 at the end  
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work for (non-square) rectangular inputs?

Comment: Only square inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your algorithm is designed to only produce a number of entries that is a multiple of 4. For a given value of `h`, the inner four loops will all execute the same number of iterations: maybe 2, 3 ... or even 0. But all four the same number. So the `.push()` is always executed a multiple of 4 times.

Now, if the input is a square matrix with *n²* entries, and *n* is even, then indeed you have a multiple of 4. But if *n* is odd, then *n²* is always one more than a multiple of 4 -- this "one more" is the entry that is not produced in your algorithm.

You did already detect that the algorithm did not produce any value for the case where *n* is 1. You added an `if` block to your code to deal with that case. You can generalise this piece of code so it does the job for any *odd* `array.length`.

Replace this:

```
if(arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
}
```

With this:

```
if (arr.length % 2 == 1) {
    output.push(arr[arr.length >> 1][arr.length >> 1]);
}
```

where `>> 1` is a binary shift with one bit, which is like an integer division by two.

Answer (score 2):

From the code it seems you are assuming that:

the number of rows is equal to number of columns = `h`

So it won't work on non-square matrices. But lets assume you are working only with square matrices.

Based on your code and assuming it works for all square matrices except for the fact that it doesn't go to the center, there is a simple fix.

The center of the `n x n` matrix in a spiral formation is :

`(n/2, n/2)` if `n` is odd

and `(n/2, n/2 - 1)` if `n` is even

So after your outer `for` loop is done, if your output length is not `h*h` then just add the value at center i.e. `(n/2, n/2)` or `(n/2, n/2-1)` based on n is even or odd.